# Error de conversión al convertir el valor nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy intentando crear un sql dinamico pero no me funciona, ya lo probe sin hacerlo dinamicamente y funciona correctamente el query por lo que eh probado el error esta por el OFFSET en adelante.

Este es el query

```
Create procedure [dbo].[getEmployeeList] ( @page INT = 1, @size INT = 10, @sort nvarchar(50) = 'Id asc', @totalrow INT = 10, @search nvarchar(50) = '', @colum nvarchar(50) = 'Id' ) AS 
BEGIN
   DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) 
   SET
      NOCOUNT 
      ON 
      SET
         @sql = '
 
         SELECT
            * 
         FROM
            [dbo].Empleado 
         WHERE
            ' + @colum + ' LIKE ''' + @search + ' % '' 
         ORDER BY
            ' + @sort + ' OFFSET ('+ @page +' - 1)* + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), '+@size+') ROWS FETCH NEXT '+@size+' ROWS ONLY;
'
 EXECUTE (@sql) 
         SET
            @totalrow = 
            (
               SELECT
                  COUNT(*) 
               FROM
                  Empleado
            )
            select
               @totalrow 
END
```

Pero no me funciona y no se como puedo arreglar ese error.

Comment: Yo sé que esto no tiene nada que ver con tu pregunta, pero salvo que se den ciertas condiciones, es una muy mala idea implementar una paginación de datos por SP, eso lo debería resolver la vista. ¿por qué digo esto? por que seguramente no puedes garantizar que Empleados tenga los mismos datos entre llamada y llamada. Por otro lado,  dices que esto no te funciona ¿Tienes algún error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay pequeños problemas en la ejecución. Además de devolverte 2 conjuntos.

He puesto un print, para que te de salida de la query que está formando el código dinámico, en la ventana de mensajes, porque la única manera de depurar el mismo, es saber lo que estás planteando.

Los errores que te mostraba, son por conversiones en Offset..... Y cuidado con los espacios de más en la búsqueda de @search

```
Create or alter procedure [dbo].[getEmployeeList] 
( 
@page INT = 1, 
@size INT = 10, 
@sort nvarchar(50) = 'Id asc', 
@totalrow INT = 10, 
@search nvarchar(50) = '', 
@colum nvarchar(50) = 'Id' 
) AS 
BEGIN
   DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) 
   SET
      NOCOUNT 
      ON 
      SET
         @sql = '
 
         SELECT
            * 
         FROM
            [dbo].Empleado  
         WHERE
            ' + @colum + ' like ''' + @search + '%'' 
         ORDER BY
            ' + @sort + ' OFFSET ('+ try_Cast(@page as varchar(10)) +' - 1)* + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), '+try_cast(@size as varchar(10))+') ROWS FETCH NEXT '+ try_cast(@size as varchar(10))+' ROWS ONLY;
'
print @sql
 EXECUTE (@sql) 
         SET
            @totalrow = 
            (
               SELECT
                  COUNT(*) 
               FROM
                  Empleado 
            )
            select
               @totalrow 
END
```

Aunque obviamente, esto no soluciona todas las búsquedas posibles, y puede darte errores de conversión en algunos tipos de datos.

```
Create table Empleado (id int, firstName varchar(25), lastName varchar(25));
Insert into Empleado(id, firstName, lastName)
values
(1,'ana','perez'),
(2,'bea','perez'),
(3,'jaime','perez'),
(4,'javier','perez'),
(5,'lucas','perez');
```

Y su ejecución.

```
exec
[dbo].[getEmployeeList]  @page = 1, @size = 10, @sort = 'Id asc', 
@totalrow = 10, @search  = 'ja', @colum  = 'firstName'
```

[image: Res]